# No module named autobahn.twisted.websocket

Tags: openfaces

```
./demos/web/start-servers.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./demos/web/websocket-server.py", line 25, in <module>
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
ImportError: No module named autobahn.twisted.websocket
```

but I is already installed like this:

```
pip install twisted

Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: twisted in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (16.0.0)
```

But why?please...

Answer (score 2):

The Traceback tells you all you need. You are missing autobahn.twisted.websockets. So basically the first thing you need is the `autobahn` package. Also you will need twisted. So do the following to install it.

```
pip install autobahn twisted
```